# Getting key pressed from key-event in Racket

Tags: events, keyboard, scheme, racket

I am trying following code to pick up up/down/right/left keys, modifying example on http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/windowing-overview.html

```
(define fr (new frame% [label "Testing"] [width 300] [height 300]))
(define msg (new message% [parent fr] [label ""]))

(define my-canvas%
  (class canvas% 
    (define/override (on-char key-event)
      (cond
        [(equal? key-event 'up) (send msg set-label "UP")]
        [(equal? key-event 'down) (send msg set-label "DOWN")]
        [(equal? key-event 'left) (send msg set-label "LEFT")]
        [(equal? key-event 'right) (send msg set-label "RIGHT")]
        [else (send msg set-label "Others")]))
    (super-new)))

(new my-canvas% [parent fr]
     [paint-callback
      (lambda (canvas dc)
        (send dc draw-ellipse 140 120 20 20))])

(send fr show #t)
```

The key-event codes are taken from http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/key-event_.html?q=event

However, the up/down/right/left keys are not correctly identified and only "Others" get displayed in the message. Where is the problem and how can this be corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Replace `(equal? key-event <key-code>)` with `(equal? (send key-event get-key-code) <key-code>)`.
2. Add `[stretchable-width #t]` to the list of initialization arguments for `msg`, otherwise you won't be able to see the output.